# how to suppress standard form/scientific notation in Pandas header?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have imported a csv into a pandas dataframe, the csv consisting of integers, including the column headers and row indices. The problem is that the column headers are converted automatically to scientific notation and when I try to identify the column by index, only the scientific notation is recognized - presumably it has been converted to a string. The original integer is not recognized. It is only an issue with the header (I can repeat the effect iwth whatever row number I choose as the header) and I see no option in read_csv to switch this behavior off.
How to I stop pandas doing this to integers in the header?

Comment: Could you share your current column names?

Comment: For example 49733779, 50086405 which become 4.973377900000000000e+07, 5.008640500000000000e+07

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce that behaviour. Could you share a minimal sample of the CSV?

Comment: ah. discovered the issue. A previous savetxt had written the csv in this odd scientific format and when I had looked at it up till now with libreoffice, libreoffice was clever enough to convert everything to normal integers so it looked OK. Looking directly at the text file shows what is really there though. Pandas was just taking what was in the header row and converting it directly to a string while it was clever enough to convert the rest into more normal format. Asking savetxt to save as %i solved it